# File System vs Database

Tags: database, file

Both file system and database are used to store data in files. The question is that which one is used more commonly in the programming industry? And in a given case, as to why file system is a more desirable option than database?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on the need of the program. Speed and indexing needs would put you in with a database, while simplicity would usually put you in with a file system. Then there's another thousand or so things to consider (environment eg. Arduino/pi/pc?, Function eg. File editor/point of sales/logging utility). Thens there are many apps that use both (I mean if you think about it, your database has to be stored on file somewhere). If you were to as, say, would a database or FS be better for, say, an employee clock in system, I would say a database. But other than that there are too many use cases to declare one better than the other